# variable datatype in Typescript code statement

Tags: javascript, typescript

In typescript documentation , like a variable type is defined as for e.g.:-

```
let var:number
```

in which var is of type number, but in the code mentioned below:-

```
namespace Validation {
    export interface StringValidator {
        isAcceptable(s: string): boolean;
    }

    const lettersRegexp = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
    const numberRegexp = /^[0-9]+$/;

    export class LettersOnlyValidator implements StringValidator {
        isAcceptable(s: string) {
            return lettersRegexp.test(s);
        }
    }

    export class ZipCodeValidator implements StringValidator {
        isAcceptable(s: string) {
            return s.length === 5 && numberRegexp.test(s);
        }
    }
}

// Some samples to try
let strings = ["Hello", "98052", "101"];

// Validators to use
let validators: { [s: string]: Validation.StringValidator; } = {};
validators["ZIP code"] = new Validation.ZipCodeValidator();
validators["Letters only"] = new Validation.LettersOnlyValidator();

// Show whether each string passed each validator
for (let s of strings) {
    for (let name in validators) {
        console.log(`"${ s }" - ${ validators[name].isAcceptable(s) ? "matches" : "does not match" } ${ name }`);
    }
}
```

In the above code , what is the meaning of the statement :-

```
let validators: { [s: string]: Validation.StringValidator; } = {};
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just a small remark, in your example 'let var: number' is not correct js/ts because var is a reserved word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is saying that the validators is an object (of type Object) whose keys are of type String and the value of type StringValidator

So basically it is just setting the type, same as `let a: number;` is saying that a is a number but with a more complex object type.

Comment: It may be better to say that `validators` is an object whose keys are of type `string` and values of type `Validation.StringValidator`. I tripped over your phrasing the first time because I thought you were saying it has a single key `s` whose type is `string`.

Comment: @Aankhen I have rephrased following your suggestion, thanks!
T.J. Crowder as per Explosion Pillls reply (which is better than mine) it is in the handbook: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types-and-string-index-signatures

Answer (score 4):

This is a [string index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types-and-string-index-signatures). This means that you can set any property on a variable of this type as long as the property name is a string (it has to be anyway) and the property value is of type `Validation.StringValidator`.

You can see this on the subsequent lines, `validators["ZIP code"] = new Validation.ZipCodeValidator();` -- this sets a string property `"ZIP code"` to a value of `ZipCodeValidator` which must extend from `StringValidator`.

The `= {}` part just assigns an empty object to `validator` at first. This is done so that you can set properties on it. If you didn't set it to an empty object, you would get an error when you tried to write to `validators["ZIP code"]`, etc.

Comment: *"...as the property name is a string (it has to be anyway)..."* Not for a few years now, ES2015 added Symbol-named properties.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder good point; seems like TypeScript doesn't support this for index signatures yet

Comment: If I am not wrong the property name will internally be casted to a string, right?

Comment: @A.Llorente - Property names can be strings or Symbols. If you use something that isn't a string or a Symbol as a property name (for instance, `a[2]`), it's coerced (converted) to string and then that string is used. Symbols are not converted to strings.

Comment: @ExplosionPills - Yeah, just tried it in the playground, and it complains it wants `string` or `number` (despite the fact that property names are never numbers, even though we routinely write them as numbers, for instance when using arrays).